# Is it possible to go to the app's specific battery optimization page or highlight it using ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to ask the user to exempt the application from battery optimizations using ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS and I want it to go directly to the app's battery usage page instead of that really confusing page i'm getting from the code below

```
private fun checkBatteryOptimizations(context: Context, start: () -> Unit) {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    val powerManager = context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
    if (!powerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(context.packageName)) {
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setMessage("If you want this app to work properly you need to exempt it from battery restrictions")
            .setPositiveButton("ok") { _, _ ->
                val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS)
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }.setNegativeButton("cancel") { _, _ ->
                start()
            }.create().show()
    } else start()
} else start()    }
```

is that even possible?